# Why is my EC2 Instance Timing out with a CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, cname-record

I setup a CNAME record at my registrar (godaddy) and pointed it to my running instance located at [ec2-204-236-164-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com](http://ec2-204-236-164-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com).

I can't seem to browse, ping, or otherwise get any verification of the address using the IP, the name above, or the DNS/CNAME registrar redirect.  Any thoughts on troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work by setting the @ name and CNAME.  With just the CNAME the attempt to connect was failing over and over.  But it's up and live now.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any A records? The final A record translation has to occur in Amazon's cloud.

Comment: I'm redirecting straight to the ec2-204-236-164-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com address with a CNAME so that Amazon would maintain the actual IP address.  I don't want to setup an Elastic IP just yet.  I do plan to do so when I go live, but for now I just want to be able to view the site (or error the site displays) that is at the address ec2-204-236-164-223.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.